# How to replace one side of a has_many through ActiveRecord model without deleting existing records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-migration

I have an ActiveRecord model with a has_many through association. The Event model has a venue column (string) which I need to extract and turn into a separate model.

```
# Original Models

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :booking_events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookings, through: :booking_events
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :booking_events, dependent: destroy
  has_many :events, through: :booking_events
end    

class BookingEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :booking
end


# Refactored models

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  has_many :booking_venues, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookings, through: :booking_venues
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :booking_venues, dependent: destroy
  has_many :venues, through: :booking_venues
end    

class BookingVenue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :booking
end
```

As Venue is now one side of the many to many through relationship instead of Event I added the venue id and used a migration to look up and associate the proper venue_id.

```
class BookingVenue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event # not needed, trying to remove
  belongs_to :booking
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

The next step is for me to remove the events association as it is no longer needed however when I delete the column or set the event_id to nil the records are deleted from the database. I think this is because of the `dependent: destroy`.

I think I am approaching this correctly however, I do not know if this is the standard or Rails way of migrating data or updating associations.  Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating new has_many through association tables and updating/renaming the model definitions to work with the new models.

The following reference was key: https://makandracards.com/makandra/15575-how-to-write-complex-migrations-in-rails

I then added model class definitions to the migration file in order to have ActiveRecord support for querying the original models. For model definitions that did not change but restricted data manipulation due to dependent values, I used the concept of open classes in Rails to override the association temporarily in the migration to change the dependent association from destroy to nullify.

For example:

```
#migration file

class CreateVenue < ActiveRecord::Migration

  # temporarily override dependent assocation
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    # has_many :booking_event, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :booking_event, dependent: :nullify
  end    

  # temporary model class definition for ActiveRecord support
  class BookingEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

   def change
     # Used the previous model support to loop through and create
     # the new association objects

     # overriding the dependent: :destroy value above allows 
     # for deleting this table without deleting the other records
     drop_table :booking_events
   end
end
```